# PuTTY won't connect with SSH - Password authentication failed

Tags: ssh, putty

I try to connect to a remote machine through SSH. It works great using SSH from a Linux Machine. But from PuTTY on a Win7 I always get a "Password authentication failed".

In the `auth.log` of the remote machine I see the `failed password` logs but I don't understand why.

Any idea what's troubling me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As odd as it sounds... perhaps you ARE typing in your password wrong.  Does your linux box and your windows box share the same keyboard layout?  Perhaps what you think is a number-sign (#) is actually a british pound sign (£)... or other such oddities.

Comment: You can look at various keyboard mappings here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964651.aspx

Comment: Yeah. I changed the remote password to something simple and I worked. Weird since I tried to type the password elsewhere. (And I discovered btw some Linux machine got the same problem)